# Magnetic fields from free currents in Griffiths' book

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In his *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, D.J. Griffiths is warning against the idea that magnetic fields $\vec B$ and $\vec H$ are similar. Here is a passage:

[image]

The equation 6.20 he is talking about is $\oint \vec{H}\cdot d\vec{r}=I_f$, where $I_f$ is the free current.

Fine. Then he presents a problem. Image below.

[image]

When I look at the solution, what do I find? He concludes that $\vec H=0$ because there is no free current. Image below

[image]

Well, now, **isn't this precisely what he just warned the reader against doing??**

Comment: this being a homework problem I can only give you a hint: a "short cylinder" and an "infinitely long cylinder" are very different things.

Comment: @hyportnex it is not homework, I am just studying this book and had this question. How exactly does the length of the cylinder make a difference? Is it that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{M}\neq 0$ at the "top" and "bottom" of the cylinder?

Comment: @hyportnex If a question like this is considered as homework or homework-like this site is going to die. Question and answers are about *conceptual understanding* of magnetism in materials. That is perfectly in agreement with this site policy.

Comment: Of course, my comment applies also to the tag editing by @Frobenius.

Comment: @GiorgioP I agree with your comment wholeheartedly, this is a fair question and in fact I upvoted the question itself; but unless I was hallucinating, as I recall now, there was a "homework" tag added to the question that since has disappeared, hence my "hint" without a detailed answer...

Comment: @hyportnex I had not used the homework tag when I asked the question, because it is not homework. Someone else added that tag, and I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @hyportnex, and correctly understood by the OP, there is an essential difference between Griffith's example in the warning and the Problem 6.12. In the former case, the cylindric magnet is *finite*, while in the latter is *infinite*. The two cases differ for a region of non-zero divergence of magnetization, precluding the possibility of getting the value of the field $\bf H$ by using only the information about zero circulation in the absence of free currents.

A picture, taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demagnetizing_field)
[image]

should make evident that the vector field $\bf H$ lines do start and end at the left and right surfaces, making non-zero the local divergence.